# After guest user session used, J. Random user appears in menu

Tags: 13.10, users

I let someone borrow my computer for email etc, and they logged into a guest session, they did their business and I logged back into my account.
And now I see a "J. Random User" in the Unity power menu applet, when logging in to my account.

Should I be concerned of malicious activity, and how do I fix this?

Comment: This is not a forum and you have no *expirences* here but this question.

Comment: @Lucio - if you were to use another email address... **@user237375** - does `ls /home` produce any unexpected usernames? *(that does depend on whether a home directory was created...)*

Comment: @Lucio My other account got banned for being a noob.

Comment: Relevant Launchpad issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ido/+bug/1256590